# How to write a file object to outbound endpoint in Mule

Tags: mule

I have a `<file:inbound-endpoint>` which reads a large file and pass it to a java component which splits large file into multiple smaller files. I add all these smaller files into a list and return `list` from java component into mule flow.

Now, in mule flow, I am using `<collection-splitter>` or `<foreach>` to output those files to the `<file:outbound-endpoint>`.

The problem is that

- It is outputting only a single file (it overwrites the file, not using the original filename for output file)
- The content of the file is filename and **not** the file content.

Comment: Does your Java component return a list of the content of these smaller files? Or just a list of file names? Have you configured an output pattern on your file outbound endpoint so a new file is created each time?

Comment: Java component returns a `List<File>` objects. Haven't configured an `outputPattern` yet, not sure how to get the file name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- You need to add a `file:file-to-byte-array-transformer` after you've split the `List<File>` and before `file:outbound-endpoint` so Mule will read the actual content of the `java.io.File`.
- You need to define an `outputPattern` on the `file:outbound-endpoint`, using a MEL expression to construct a unique file name based on the properties of the in-flight message and also on other expressions, like timestamp or a UUID, whatever fits your needs.

Comment: Thanks David for your response. I got 1st part working but struggling to get filename as outputPattern. I give filename in my Splitter class to each smaller file and want to use the same name when outputting to outbound-endpoint.

Answer (score 3):

or 1st I did as @David suggested to add `file:file-to-byte-array-transformer`.

For 2nd part, to get the name of file outputting to `<file:outbound-endpoint>` same as the file name assigned while creating file, I did following:

```
    <foreach>
        <set-variable variableName="fname" value="#[payload.path]"/>
        <logger level="INFO" message="fname is: #[fname]" />
        <file:file-to-byte-array-transformer />  
        <file:outbound-endpoint path="${file.csv.path}" outputPattern="#[fname]"/> 
    </foreach>
```

Before converting file to byte array, get the file name as after byte array conversion, its not available in `#[payload]` though you may still get it from `#[originalPayload]`